# Polar curves with the "cardioid property" (divisibility into arbitrarily-many equal-length arcs via straightedge and compass)

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates, geometric-construction

In the 2005 *American Mathematical Monthly* article ["Geometry and Number Theory on Clovers" (JSTOR link)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30037571?seq=1), Cox and Shurman state as their Theorem 2:

> **Cardioid Theorem.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then the cardioid can be divided into $n$ arcs of equal length using a straightedge and compass.

I'm calling the property that a curve may be divided into arbitrarily-many arcs of equal length using a straightedge and compass the "Cardioid Property". My question:

> What other polar curves have the Cardioid Property? I have found next-to-nothing on this topic in literature.

Cox and Shurman note that the circle and [(Bernoulli) lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli) can be divided into $n$ equal-length arcs via straightedge and compass iff $n=2^a p_1 p_2\cdots p_r$ where the $p_i$ are distinct Fermat primes. (These results are originally due, respectively, to Gauss and Abel.) The authors focus on "origami" constructions on "$m$-clovers" $r^{m/2} = \cos\frac{m}{2}\theta$ (particularly, $m=3$ and $m=4$ (the lemniscate)).

Comment: ...then you'd better learn how to spell "cardioid."